# Phonegap cookie iOS differences between 4.3 and 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios5, cordova, ios4

I have the following problem:

My phonegap app makes use of cookies to perform user authentication.

It works on the 4.3 simulators in XCode, but as soon as I switch to the 5.0 simulators the server responds with "Error: No session". 
It seems that either the cookie is not submitted to the server or that the cookies are somehow modified??
When I start the 4.3 iPhone/iPad simulators it works perfectly.

Any suggestions why?

Comment: Please describe how exactly you are setting the cookies/user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally narrowed it down to our usage of JSONP because we also want to use the app as a mobile website.

In iOS 4.3 JSONP worked perfectly, but on iOS5 it seems to cause problems with cookie authenticaton, whereas the JSONP part seems to work (I get the right answer and so on), but not the cookie authentication anymore.